# NoMethodError undefined method map for parent model's object: RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to do a object.map() on all the objects I return by find_by(:secondary_id => id).

In my Routes:

```
result = Models::Persistence::User.all.where(:auth_id => authid)
result =  result.to_a.map{my function}
```

Model user:

```
embeds_many :useractivity
```

and embedded model useractivity:

```
embedded_in :users, class_name:"Models::Persistence::User"
```

I get the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `map' for #<Models::Persistence::User:0x007fca14fd7330>
```

The other answers on SO talk about how it is undefined for a nil:NilClass. How can I fix this?

I've tried using the .all as well.

Ruby Version I'm using: ruby 2.2.0p0

When I do:

```
resultAll =  Models::Persistence::User.all()
```

I don't get any errors and I can view all the objects in resultAll[0-n]

Comment: Does Models::Persistence::User extend from ActiveRecord::Base?

Comment: The NoMethodError above is without the all().  Can you post the error messages you get when you use all() as in Models::Persistence::User.all()

Comment: Ok, so I wanted to get this working. Though it doesn't answer my question, I found a workaround: 1. Convert the Object to a hash, explicitly using result.attributes and then run your function on it.

Comment: Code: 
resultHash = resultObjFromFind_By_Method.attributes
finalResult = Hash.new
resultHash.each do //Blah

Comment: Please, pardon me the ignorance and if this comment is totally useless, but this is the first time I ever see using `map` in `routes.rb` ... I mean in this sense...

Comment: Oh no, you're right! I am working off a small project for  prototype, and I'm trying to fix it. It's entirely my mistake to have a crappy architecture. It should rightly belong to my models. :)